# How to define a structure with a pointer-type item?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef, void-pointers

I have a `typedef struct` but with a pointer type naming `*Ptype` as shown below -

```
typedef struct
{
    int InputIntArg1;
    int InputIntArg2;
    char InputCharArg1;
} *Ptype;
```

I want to define an item (`Item1`) and assign numbers to its members(`InputIntArg1` & `InputIntArg2`). However, `Item1` is a pointer. Is it possible not to change the typedef naming (`*Ptype`) and do a correct declaration?

```
int main(void)
{
    Ptype Item1; // <---------- How to modify this line?
    Ptype Item2;

    Item1.InputIntArg1 = 1;
    Item1.InputIntArg2 = 7;
    Item2 = &Item1;
    printf("Num1 = %d \n", Item2->InputIntArg1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not hide a pointer to a struct with a typedef.

Perhaps use:

```
typedef struct
{
    int InputIntArg1;
    int InputIntArg2;
    char InputCharArg1;
} Type;
```

Then you can write:

```
int main(void)
{
    Type Item1;
    Type *Item2;

    Item1.InputIntArg1 = 1;
    Item1.InputIntArg2 = 7;
    Item2 = &Item1;
    printf("Num1 = %d \n", Item2->InputIntArg1);
}
```

So what happens then:

- Item1 is a Ptype struct
- Item2 is a pointer to a Ptype struct
- with the assignment `Item2 = &Item1;` Item2 points now to the Item1 struct
- using the Item2 pointer you are now accessing the values of the Item1 struct

Comment: I generally agree; though it's "ok" so long as the pointer type is clearly a pointer type with `ptr` or some other obvious pre/postfix. At least I've dealt with plenty of codebases that do this :)

Comment: I agree, there's a big codebase that does that. IMHO the use of explicit pointers is more readable. Of course, it also depends on which code style was agreed within the team. One should of course stick to that. But my personal preference here is definitely the explicit use of pointers :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to refer to the anonymous struct type itself from just `Ptype`. The best you can do is add the base type and pointer types in the same type definition:

```
typedef struct
{
    int InputIntArg1;
    int InputIntArg2;
    char InputCharArg1;
} type, *Ptype;
```

Then just use `type` for the actual struct and `Ptype` for a pointer to it.